# Run powershell in PHP with new-Object

Tags: php, windows, powershell, cmd

I have to manage a cash register from PHP. If I run the following commands via cmd there are no problems. The cash register print the string perfectly.

I write the commands in this order:

```
powershell
[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()
$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM1,9600,None,8,one
$port.open()
$port.WriteLine("1R")
// Print string 1R on cash register
```

The problem comes when I try to do this from php. I created a web server ( XAMPP ) to ensure that it can send commands from php to the serial port . I tried various ways of writing the script, but none of them work. Here's an example of my .php

```
<?php
$patch = "c:\\Windows\\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
$runCMD1 = $patch .'[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()';
$runCMD2 = '$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM1,9600,None,8,on';
$runCMD3 = '$port.open()';
$runCMD4 = '$port.WriteLine("1R")';

exec($runCMD1, $out1); // Return COM1
exec($runCMD2, $out2); // Return Nothing
exec($runCMD3, $out3); // Return Nothing
exec($runCMD3, $out3); // Return Nothing
?>
```

Everyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you execute `powershell.exe` you're passing only one line of the script to the completely new instance. That's why it doesn't work. You need to pass whole script to the single powershell instance. This can be done several ways:

Via StandradInput:

```
powershell.exe -Command - < script.ps1
```

Via single-line argument for  `Command` parameter:

```
powershell.exe -Command '[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames() ; $port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM1,9600,None,8,one ; $port.open() ; $port.WriteLine("1R")'
```

Via [Base64 string](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timid/archive/2014/03/26/powershell-encodedcommand-and-round-trips.aspx) to `EncodedCommand` argument :

```
powershell.exe -EncodedCommand 'WwBTAHkAcwB0AGUAbQAuAEkATwAuAFAAbwByAHQAcwAuAFMAZQByAGkAYQBsAFAAbwByAHQAXQA6ADoAZwBlAHQAcABvAHIAdABuAGEAbQBlAHMAKAApACAAOwAgACQAcABvAHIAdAA9ACAAbgBlAHcALQBPAGIAagBlAGMAdAAgAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtAC4ASQBPAC4AUABvAHIAdABzAC4AUwBlAHIAaQBhAGwAUABvAHIAdAAgAEMATwBNADEALAA5ADYAMAAwACwATgBvAG4AZQAsADgALABvAG4AZQAgADsAIAAkAHAAbwByAHQALgBvAHAAZQBuACgAKQAgADsAIAAkAHAAbwByAHQALgBXAHIAaQB0AGUATABpAG4AZQAoACIAMQBSACIAKQA='
```

Or you can just drop temporary file to disk:

```
powershell.exe -File 'C:\Windows\Temp\tempscript.ps1'
```

Comment: I have try this code `powershell.exe -Command '[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames() ; $port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM1,9600,None,8,one ; $port.open() ; $port.WriteLine("1R")'` in cmd but don't work.

Comment: @Andreaphp, to use the EncodedCommand switch you have to format the input like this: shell_exec("powershell -EncodedCommand " . base64_encode(iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE", utf8_encode('YOUR_PS_COMMAND_STRING'))));

Answer (score 0):

**The solution:**

.PHP file:

```
<?php
$scriptname = 'script.ps1';
$runCMD = "powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted - Command - < $scriptname";
exec($runCMD,$out);
echo join($out);
?>
```

.ps1 file:

```
[System.IO.Port.SerialPort]::getportnames()
$port= new-Object System.IO.Port.SerialPort COM1,9600,None,8,one
$port.open()
$port.WriteLine("1R")
```

Thanks to @beatcracker